# how can i add Bi directional lines in azure maps

Tags: maps, azure-maps

is there any way we can add two polylines between two coordinates
new atlas.data.LineString([[point A],[point B]])
new atlas.data.LineString([[point B],[point A]])
like this
currently it shows only one line when i add this to data source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have one linestring and you want a second linestring with coordinates in the opposite order, you can create a deep copy of the linestring, and then reverse the coordinate array, then add the lines to the data source. For example, if you have a GeoJSON linestring object:

```js
var line = new atlas.data.LineString([[-73.972340, 40.743270], [-74.004420, 40.756800]]);

//Create a deep copy of the line.
var newLine  = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(line));

//Reverse the order of the coordinates in the new line.
newLine.coordinates.reverse();
```

As you noted, these lines will overlap when rendered. What you can do to add a visual separation, turn one of these into a GeoJSON feature and add a unique property that can be seen by the data driven styles, then use the offset option of the `LineLayer`. For example:

```js
//Create a feature from the line and add some property we can use to know this is a reverse copy of a line when styling.
var newFeature = new atlas.data.Feature(newLine, { isCopy: true });

//Add the feature to the data source instead of the new line.
datasource.add(newFeature);

//Have two-line layers with a filter 

//Line layer for original lines.
map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    offset: -2,
    filter: ['!', ['has', 'isCopy']]
})); 

//A second line layer that renders the line copies
map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    offset: 2,
    filter: ['has', 'isCopy']
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

if it is just the Polyline you want to plot between points and indicate with two different colors, you can use the *offset* property of **LineLayerOptions** and plot the lines using the following JavaScript.

```
  var dataSource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
  map.sources.add(dataSource);

  //Create a line and add it to the data source.
  dataSource.add(new atlas.data.LineString([[-73.972340, 40.743270], [-74.004420, 40.756800]]));

  //Create a line layer to render the line to the map.
  map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
    strokeColor: 'green',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    offset: -2
  })); 
  
  map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.LineLayer(dataSource, null, {
    strokeColor: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 1,
    offset: 2
  })); 
});
```

The above JavaScript would produce the following Ploy Lines on Azure Maps.

[image]

Optionally, you can add a distinct data source if you prefer and map the layers for each data source. But you can achieve the same output by using a single data source as indicated above.

I have built the JavaScript code based on the Azure Maps documentation [Add Line Layer to the Map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-line-layer) where you can find great code references to add symbols and line gradients. Here is the link to the [LineLayers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.linelayeroptions?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#properties) interface which provides a list of options that you can use when rendering line layers in Azure Map.

Comment: I already know this offset functionality but I want to add bi-directional lines with two LineString as I have datasource in which there will be some single lines as well as bidirectional lines  between coordinates

Comment: When you say bidirectional, do you want to display it by showing arrow symbols on each polyline as shown in the sample [Add symbols along a line[(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-line-layer#add-symbols-along-a-line)